# Easily Editing XAML Color Resources in Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, xaml-designer

From the XAML designer in Visual Studio it is possible to place your cursor into the `Color` attribute of a Brush element and easily access the color Editor.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="#FF4B4B4B" />
```

In the above case, if you place the cursor before in the `#` in the XAML, then you can access the color from the properties view shown in the image below, it is easily accessed under the "Appearance" section.

[image]

That works great, the issue is only when one would like to do the same with a `Color` resource that is defined like this instead.

```
<Color x:Key="MyBrushColor">#FF4D7BBF</Color>
```

In the above case, placing the cursor in front of the `#` apparently does NOT cause Visual Studio to display the color editor anywhere in the properties view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after I posted this, I see how to do it, hope this helps someone else.

- Place the cursor in the `Color` element.
- Right-click on the "Color" box in the Properties View and select `Edit Resource...`